# Alternating Series Divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Test the series for convergence:
$$ -2/5 + 4/6 - 6/7 + 8/8 - 10/9$$

Attempted Solution:

$$a_n = (-1)^n,\; b_n = \frac{2n}{4+n}$$

$$b_n\not\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\implies \sum_n a_n$$

is divergent by the alternating series test.

According to the answer key, $a_n$ should be convergent. I can't understand why; Is my expression for $a_n$ correct as maybe that is where the error lies.

Incase any1 is confused, trying to prove convergence of $a_n$

Comment: You don't even need the alternating series, you can just use the nth term test, since the terms don't go to $0$.

Comment: @AdamHughes Are you referring to the fact that if limit of $a_n$ doesn't equal zero then series($a_n$) is divergent

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: But according to my answer key, this series is convergent??

Comment: the series ....

Comment: Then you're solid on divergence. I don't understand what you have that $a_n$ for, unless you mean $a_n=(-1)^nb_n$ with $b_n={2n\over 4+n}$ and not the negative version. Then you're also **not** talking about convergence of the $a_n$, you're talking about the sum.

In either case, there's no problem:  answer keys < theorems. They made an error.